# most frequent words in a french text

Tags: python, text, nltk, stop-words

I am using the python `nltk` package to find the most frequent words in a French text. I find it not really working...
Here is my code:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#nltk: package for text analysis
from nltk.probability import FreqDist
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk
import tokenize
import codecs
import unicodedata


#output French accents correctly
def convert_accents(text):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).encode('ascii', 'ignore')



### MAIN ###

#openfile
text_temp=codecs.open('text.txt','r','utf-8').readlines()

#put content in a list
text=[]
for word in text_temp:
    word=word.strip().lower()
    if word!="":
        text.append(convert_accents(word))

#tokenize the list
text=nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(str(text))

#use FreqDist to get the most frequents words
fdist = FreqDist()
for word in  text:
    fdist.inc( word )
print "BEFORE removing meaningless words"
print fdist.items()[:10]

#use stopwords to remove articles and other meaningless words
for sw in stopwords.words("french"):
     if fdist.has_key(sw):
          fdist.pop(sw)
print "AFTER removing meaningless words"
print fdist.items()[:10]
```

Here is the output:

```
BEFORE removing meaningless words
[(',', 85), ('"', 64), ('de', 59), ('la', 47), ('a', 45), ('et', 40), ('qui', 39), ('que', 33), ('les', 30), ('je', 24)]
AFTER removing meaningless words
[(',', 85), ('"', 64), ('a', 45), ('les', 30), ('parce', 15), ('veut', 14), ('exigence', 12), ('aussi', 11), ('pense', 11), ('france', 10)]
```

My problem is that `stopwords` does not discard all the meaningless words.
For example ',' is not a word and should be removed, 'les' is an article and should be removed.

How to fix the problem?

The text I used can be found at this page:
http://www.elysee.fr/la-presidence/discours-d-investiture-de-nicolas-sarkozy/

Comment: If the `stopwords` offered by `nltk` don't suit you, then you should do you own list with the stopwords you want to be removed, or look for another library. As for the commas `,` you can try `newstr = oldstr.replace(",", "")` in the whole text, before any other work on it.

Comment: Ok for your suggestions. But how come the `nltk stopwords` functionality does not do the job it is supposed to do?!!!

Comment: I took a look at the french `stopwords` from `nltk`, and I would say it's pretty complete (I also talk french). Just a few more words, like "ils", "elles", "les", "leurs" (mainly plurals), and it would be done. I guessed the guys that wrote the `Stopwords Corpus` which is used in `nltk`, didn't know french so well. But it is not like we can complain, after all they gave us a magnificient library for free !

Comment: Ok thanks, `user823743` gave another good explanation as well ;).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually its a better idea to use a list of stopwords of your own. For this purpose, you can get a list of French stopwords from [here](http://www.ranks.nl/stopwords/french). The article word 'les' is also on the list. Create a text file of them and use the file to remove stopwords from your corpus. Then for punctuations you have to write a punctuation removal function. How you should write it, highly depends on your application. But just to show you a few examples that would get you started, you can write:

```
import string
t = "hello, eric! how are you?"
print t.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
```

and the output is:

```
hello eric how are you
```

or, another way is to simply write:

```
t = t.split()
for w in t:
    w = w.strip('\'"?,.!_+=-')
    print w
```

So, it really depends on how you need them to be removed. In certain scenarios these methods might not result in what you exactly wanted. But, you can build on them. Let me know if you had any further questions.

Comment: Ok for your suggestions. I guess I will end up using your solution...  But how come the `nltk stopwords` functionality does not do the job it is supposed to do?!!!

Comment: Because the team who developed nltk might not spoke all the languages that nltk covered, they most likely used a huge corpus of text for each language and found the most common words that were used in that corpus as stop words. So this list was probably generated automatically. Also, stop words vary based on application. For example, stop words in the context of topic classification are different than that in the context of sentiment classification. That's why, at the end of the day a rough list of stop words was enough from the point of view of developers.